# prerender url after click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use prefetch and prerender on my site. However I don't want to unnecessary load other sites. So I only want to prefetch/prerender after the user has clicked on a certain element on the page.

I cannot find a way to check if my code is correct.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
        <link rel="prefetch" href="url"/>
        <link rel="prerender" href="url"/>
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of prefetch/prerender library? Because the code you posted is invalid.

Comment: SImplest is to look in browser dev tools console (F12) and you will immediately see that this code is throwing errors. You can't mix html in the middle of javascript unless it is quoted strings used in variables

Comment: Why do you want to do the prefetch from js? Just build your html with the proper semantics and let the browser do it

Answer (score 1):

You code is totally incorrect, first of all, create DOM element, assign attributes, append to document. Here's sample

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'prefetch');
link.setAttribute('href', 'url');
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

If you want append only on click, insert the code above into click event

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'prefetch');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'url');
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    });
});
```

But i'm now sure why would you append on click event, maybe better to execute it on dom loaded event, anyway that should help you to get things done

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this with jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function () {

        var links = '<link rel="prefetch" href="url"/>' +
                    '<link rel="prerender" href="url"/>';

        $('head').append(links);

        //   OR

        var $link1 = $('<link>', {rel : 'prefetch', href : 'url'});
        var $link2 = $('<link>', {rel : 'prerender', href : 'url'});

        $('head').append($link1, $link2);

        //   OR

        var $link1 = $('<link>').attr('rel', 'prefetch').attr('href', 'url');
        var $link2 = $('<link>').attr('rel', 'prerender').attr('href', 'url');

        $('head').append($link1).append($link2);

    });
});
```